# Add html tags to every letter in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a string of letters within a div - such as this...

```
<div>hello</div>
```

I'd like to add a html tag to each letter in the string so it will be - such as this

```
<div>
    <span>h</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>o</span>
</div>
```

Since the letters within this div will be dynamically changing it can't be static thus I'd like to use jquery to apply spans to every letter of the string.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: It seems you forgot to post jQuery code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few steps:

1. Grab the text contents and create an array of individual characters,
2. Empty the original container,
3. Add each letter as a span element.

The code:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var letters = $(this).text().split(''),
    $container = $(this).empty();

    $.each(letters, function(_, letter) {
       $('<span>', {text: letter}).appendTo($container);
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/wahitozu/1/)

Comment: After testing out everyone's answer I decided I liked this approach the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can just split the *textContent* then join it up again with suitable markup embedded. So presuming you have a reference to the div:

```
div.innerHTML = '<span>' + (div.textContent || div.innerText).split('').join('<\/span><span>') + '<\/span>';
```

#### Edit

There's always one kill–joy who points out the obvious flaw!! Ok, here's something more robust.

```
function spanizeText(element) {
  var text = (element.textContent || element.innerText).split('');
  element.innerHTML = '';

  text.forEach(function(c) {
    var sp = document.createElement('span');
    sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c));
    element.appendChild(sp);
  });
}
```

It requires a polyfil for forEach in old browsers, or change *forEach* to a plain *for* loop (same number of lines of code, probably runs faster). It could be modified to accept a wrapper element that was setup with various attributes and properties that is cloned rather than use *document.createElement*.

Comment: What about characters like `>` and `<`?

Comment: It seems like this is the most minimal answer thus I'd like to accept it, however I truthfully can't seem to make it work. Will keep trying though! thanks

Comment: Killing joy since 1978 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
var xDiv = $('div');
var xChars = $.trim(xDiv.text()).split('');
xDiv.empty();

$.each(xChars,function(i,val){
  xDiv.append($('<span>'+ val +'</span>'));
});
```

Comment: .empty() makes the div empty, and thus doesn't work. When I remove .empty() it works however it will display as <div>hello<span>h</span><span>e</span>....</div>

I can probably figure out to fix this though! Thanks

Comment: @user3104155 yeah that's right, i just corrected it;

Comment: Text may contain `>` or `<` which will mess up the markup.

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code

```
<div id="str">hello</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

JS Code

```
$(function(){
    var str= $('div#str').html();
    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        $('div#result').append('<span>'+str[i]+'</span>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/72GEt/2/) demoing one way to do this.

1. Select text
2. Split text into an *Array* of letters
3. Iterate over the *Array* and append to target element

Jquery

```
// For all matching elements
$(string).each(function() {

    // Get contents of string
    var myStr = $(this).html();

    // Split myStr into an array of characters
    myStr = myStr.split("");

    // Append strings to the result div in spans
    for (var i = 0, len = myStr.length; i < len; i++) {
        $("#result").append("<span>"  + myStr[i] + "</span>");
    }
});
```

Html output

```
<div id="letters">hello world</div>

<div id="result">
  <span>h</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span> </span>
  <span>w</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>d</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = $("div").text();
var html = [];
for(var i in txt) html.push("<span>" + txt[i] + "</span>");
$("div").html(html.join(""));
```

I wouldn't use html() or append() with every character. This will force the browser to re-calc with every call. It's better to build your content and update when ready.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a regex:

```
//var s = 'hello';
var s = $('#myDiv').html(); // get the string from the div

var newStr = s.replace(/(.)/gi, function(str, g1) {
    return '<span>' + g1 + '</span>';
});

alert(newStr);
```